# Material UI version 0.20.0 Autocomplete does not support keyboard accessibility on key press

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Hi I am using Material UI version 0.20.0 in my project. I am using the [Autocomplete component](https://v0.mui.com/#/components/auto-complete).

When I search the value and select the value using mouse its gets selected but I when I navigate the option using keyboard its goes navigates up and down using keyboard up and down arrow but on enter the highlighted values does not get selected.

I went through its docs but it does not support keyboard selection accessibility.

```
<AutoComplete
  filter={AutoComplete.caseInsensitiveFilter}
  onBlur={this.onBlur}
  hintText={this.props.hintText}
  searchText={this.state.searchText}
  menuStyle={{ maxHeight: "300px" }}
  className={this.props.className}
  floatingLabelText={this.props.floatingLabelText}
  name={this.props.name}
  textFieldStyle={this.props.textFieldStyle}
  dataSource={isSearchTextEmpty ? [] : this.props.dataSource}
  dataSourceConfig={this.props.dataSourceConfig}
  openOnFocus={this.props.openOnFocus}
  onUpdateInput={this.onUpdateInput}
  placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
  errorText={this.props.errorText}
  onFocus={this.handleOnFocus}
  open={true}
  onKeyPress={(e) => {
    console.log("KP", e);
  }}
/>;
```

Selection using keyboard enter press is working in the latest version of Material UI:

https://mui.com/material-ui/api/autocomplete/.